# Matrix representation of Clifford algebra - steps

Tags: spinors, textbook-erratum, clifford-algebra

In (Vaz and da Rocha, 2016;pg108) the following two step process is given for finding the matrix representation of a Clifford algebra: (verbatim; except for notation)

> (1) Choose a set of $N$ primitive idempotents $f_A$ ($A=1,...,N$) of
>   $\mathscr{C}{l}_{p,q}$ such that $\sum_A f_A=1$, with one of them 
>   being a primitive idempotent, for instance $f_1$.
>
> (2) Choose elements $\{\mathscr{E}_{A1}\}$ and $\{\mathscr{E}_{1a}\}$
>   ($A=1,...,N$) such that $f_1=\mathscr{E}_{1A} \mathscr{E}_{A1}$ and
>   that eqn (4.43) holds, namely,
>   $f_B\mathscr{E}_{A1}=\delta_{AB}\mathscr{E}_{A1}$ and
>   $\mathscr{E}_{1A}f_B=\delta_{AB}\mathscr{E}_{1A}$.

I am confused by the first point; Do all my $f_A$'s need to be primitive or just one of them?

Comment: Might [math.se] be better suited for this math question?

Comment: @KyleKanos I am not sure. Math SE doesn't even have a 'spinor' tag and since Spinors (a concept used more in physics then in maths) are defined using Clifford algebras I thought it best to post it here - although I might be wrong and am happy for it to be migrated to MSE.

Comment: This question was 1 close vote short of a full migration to [math.se]. Note that the [Phys.SE community usually welcomes math questions relevant for physics](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/5713/2451). I closed it as H&E to buy the Phys.SE community more time to decide what to do.

Comment: @Quantumspaghettification Your question as stated does not refer to spinor tags... or maybe we need to read the reference to get the connection with spinors?